# Fire animation on every click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am just trying to fire animation on every click with animate.css by jquery. My code is firing the animation only first time.

**HTML**

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="a-input" name="input">
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#next").click(function() {
            $('#a-input').removeClass().addClass('animated shake');
        });
```

What I am doing wrong !

Comment: Add the relevant CSS code

Comment: The relevant CSS is here: [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because on the second time, the button already has the `animated shake` classes. The remove then add occurs at the same time... So there is no difference for the element.

Say the animation lasts 600ms...

Use `setTimeout()` to remove those classes once the animation is done.

The result would be:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  $('#a-input').addClass('animated shake');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#a-input').removeClass();
  },650);
});
```

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  $('#a-input').addClass('animated shake');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#a-input').removeClass();
  },650);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="a-input" name="input">
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: But somehow this doesn't remove the class.Are you check this?

Comment: I added a snippet.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you let me know how to add a snippet..

Comment: @Danish: look for the snippet button when you edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass` from jquery :

```js
    $( "#next" ).click(function() {
      $('#a-input').effect( "shake" );
    });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="a-input" name="input"> <button id="next">Next</button>
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Comment: Are you sure? it will work if I use `$( this )` .

Comment: Updated as per requirement. @Hobo

Comment: added a snippet, just leaned how to :)

Comment: The togleClass makes the user need to click twice to see the animation...

Comment: Its need two click please fix this. @Danish

Comment: @Hobo Please check now, it is more clean code ..

Comment: Cleaner code, I agree... But the "shake" effect here is not the same effect has the one in animate.css.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette hmm, ok.